# How do I convert SCSS into CSS efficiently

Tags: css, sass, frontend, visual-studio-code

I'm using SCSS compiler extention on VS code still the active class is not getting converted to css format.
I was trying to use this `scss` file in my code but it won't work properly what to do, I'm new at this please help me.

**scss code:**

```css
#sideMenu {
  background: $lightpurple;
  max-width: 280px;
  
  nav {
    padding-top: 100px;
    
    a {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 15px 30px;
      
      &:active {
        background: $darkpurple;
        border-left: 5px solid $neon;
        padding: 15px 30px 15px 30px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: have you got the extension installed in your vs code?

Comment: the sass is OK, maybe it's your understanding of `:active` that is incorrect ?

Comment: @AmauryHanser the question is about a problem with compilation, not the SASS.

Comment: Then you should have an error when you try to compile.